# Why is eval failing to create the right alias?

Tags: bash, alias, quotes

I have this code:

```
foo=bar
eval alias $foo="echo $foo"
```

but the alias gets created as

```
alias bar='echo'
```

and not

```
alias bar='echo bar'
```

Why is `$foo` not getting expanded properly in alias definition?

Comment: Does `eval alias bar="\"echo $foo\""` work the way you work?

Comment: Yes, it does!  You can post it as an answer with explanation and I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the `set -x` log, ie. at https://ideone.com/LNazVj (the value is expanded, but not into the argument from which the alias's value is taken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
eval alias bar="\"echo $foo\""
```

or just:

```
eval alias bar=\"echo $foo\"
```

The point is to pass double quotes as literal quotes to `eval`
command.  You can check how `Bash` would parse a given command using
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> keybinding that invokes `shell-expand-line` by first
typing a command:

```
eval alias bar="\"echo $foo\""
```

And then executing the keybinding instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note that if `eval alias $foo="echo $foo"` is typed this is shown:

```
eval alias bar=echo bar
```

but when `eval alias bar=\"echo $foo\"` is typed this is shown:

```
eval alias bar="echo bar"
```